# PDO query not working with a $_COOKIE

Tags: php

I have a login system with PDO, that stores the username of the person when they log in into a cookie.
This means when they reach the redirected page, the cookie can used to fetch more data of that user (eg. first name and second name).

**This is the code setting the cookie in the index.php file:**

`setcookie('username',$username,time() + (86400 * 7));`

**This is the code which i want to fetch the data using the value of the cookie:**

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];

$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' ');
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $r->firstname, '<br>';
    echo $r->secondname, '<br>';

}
```

Every time I run the code, it returns this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\home.php on line 17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' ')
```

to:

```
("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' ")
```

which explains the syntax error.

---

Edited for added security:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$query = $handler->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =:username");
$query->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username
));

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
echo $r->firstname, '<br>';
echo $r->secondname, '<br>';
```

Comment: blah blah blah, that's all I can gather. However, I do appreciate you showing you downvoted, I'll respect that. The OP wanted a fix, it's done. @YourCommonSense Now, stop looking for cracks in the walls when there's already wallpaper. Oh, and quit stalking me, I'll report you to SO if I have to; don't mess with me.

Comment: _"There's nothing common about sense"._ That is all.

Comment: Anytime you're ready @SAMTHEMAN999 Plus, I made a slight edit.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I was going to add the security AFTER I had this problem fixed,so it would be appreciated if you removed the downvote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the edit, it made my life a bit more easier!

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Especially the comment _take your tools and get out. You can pick up your ticket at the box office._ was **epic-hilarious !**

Comment: Yeah, I'm particularly fond of that one @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: Thanks Shankar, take care my friend @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: I will, you too! @ShankarDamodaran ciao ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Although your error is a silly parse error, here is how you should do it **properly**

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_COOKIE['username']])
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $r->firstname, '<br>';
    echo $r->secondname, '<br>';
}
```

by the way, with such a login system everyone will be able to log in under everyone else's name

Comment: Dude, don't make it any more complicated. Fix the problem, take your tools and get out. You can pick up your ticket at the box office. Oh, I'm not the downvoting type, should anyone downvote you; *it's not my style*, unlike some people I know.